# Linear differential equation and harmonic motion problem

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

An atom undergoes simple harmonic motion.

Initially its displacement is $1$, its velocity is $1$ and acceleration is $-12$

compute its displacement and acceleration when the velocity is square root of $8$.

I found out that simple harmonic motion has a equation $X=A\cos(wt)$

then its velocity is derivative of $X$, which is $-AW\sin(wt)$

But, $-AW\sin(wt)$ can never be $1$ when $t=0$ because it says that its initial velocity is $1$.

Where did I misunderstand this question?

Comment: did you add constant of integration ?

Comment: The model should be $A\cos \omega t+B\sin \omega t$, or alternately $C\sin(\omega t+\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $x(t)=A\cos\omega t)$ for simple harmonic motion is *not* the general solution: It reflects the case where the atom is at rest at time $t=0$. For a truly generic simple harmonic solution, an overall phase must be included in the cosine i.e. $x(t)=A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$. From this, the initial values of position, velocity, and acceleration can be used to deduce $A,\omega,$ and $\phi$.